# A browser which allows to manually change margins while printing

Tags: software-recommendation, firefox, printing, chromium

**What I want**
I have filled a online form for admission. I need to take print of it to a file, but there are certain conditions.

- There should be no Header or footer
- Page should be A4 sized.
- All 4 margins(i.e top, bottom, left and right) should be 0.25

---

**What I tried**
While using print to file option in Firefox, I can fulfill first 2 prerequisites but the margin is always 0.5. I went to `about:config` and changed the advanced settings as

```
printer_Print_to_File.print_margin_bottom;0.25
printer_Print_to_File.print_margin_left;0.25
printer_Print_to_File.print_margin_right;0.25
printer_Print_to_File.print_margin_top;0.25
```

Still I get 0.5 margin while printing.

Then I tried `chromium browser`. Here too I can fulfill first 2 prerequisites but margin is set to `0.4`. I googled but did not find a solution to change it to `0.25`

---

**What I ask**

So I want you to either provide a way by which I could change the margins to 0.25 in one of the above browsers, or provide some browser where I could fulfill all 3 prerequisites

Of course I use Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the problem was fixed by resetting Firefox to it's default state.

1. Go to `Help ->Troubleshooting Information`
2. Select `Reset Firefox` as shown in Image.
   [image]
3. Now set the following options(or relative similar options) to desired value.

   ```
   printer_Print_to_File.print_margin_bottom
   printer_Print_to_File.print_margin_left
   printer_Print_to_File.print_margin_right
   printer_Print_to_File.print_margin_top
   ```
4. Now you can print the file.