# Print margins on Firefox (also with Print Edit)?

Tags: firefox, printing, pdf

How can I edit the print margins in Firefox in Ubuntu 14.04? I would like to print a page in A3, with custom page margins, to a PDF...

There are suggestions out there like "[setting print margins is done in the printer settings](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/994140)" - but, I absolutely cannot find anything related to print page margins... Here's what I'm trying to print:

[image: ff1]

In the Print dialog/General, there's nothing related to margins:

[image: ff2]

In the Print dialog/Page Setup, there's nothing related to margins:

[image: ff3]

---

EDIT: As per comment, the contents of "Paper size" ("US Letter"):

### [image: ff3-papersize]

In the Print dialog/Options, there's nothing related to margins:

[image: ff4]

I even installed the [Print Edit](https://addons.mozilla.org/da/firefox/addon/print-edit/) extension, also that has nothing obvious related to page margins:

[image: ff5]

So, how can I control page margins in Firefox in Ubuntu?

EDIT: I found [Where is the Print Setup setting in Firefox so top and bottom margins print on the page (now too high and too low)? | Firefox Support Forum | Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1061569) (2015):

> This is hidden and a little obscure... Firefox stores properties for each of your printers, including the "unwriteable" margin distance and the "edge" distance. ...
>   (1) In a new tab, type or paste `about:config` in the address bar and press Enter. ...
>   (3) Double-click the `print.printer_BrandX.print_edge_top` preference and enter your desired distance in hundreds of an inch. ...

So to update the question - is there a way to set print page margins in Firefox from a GUI (without changing `about:config` settings directly)?

Comment: On Windows it's in File > Page Setup > Margins & Header/Footer...

Comment: What's on "US Letter" ? Third image.

Comment: Thanks @wb9688 - as visible in the first image, there is no "File > Page Setup" in the Linux version...

Comment: Thanks @user3005629 - I have just updated my post with the image of the contents of "Paper size" ("US Letter")...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click on the Main menu and choose **Print**

Go to the top and clik **Page setup**

[image: Step one]

Then click on where you would choose **A3** and go to the bottom of the list to **Manage custom...** click on that option and you'll be presented with this box.

[image: Step 2]

If you want to use Chromium in the future just press **CTRL + P** and click on **Margins -> Custom** on the left panel.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks @user3005629 - great to have this as workaround, but I'd still like to see if someone finds a solution for Firefox...

Comment: I know, I'll check FF today.

Comment: Done! You're good to go. Tell me if any troubles.

Comment: That was what I was looking for @user3005629 - many thanks!

Comment: Well, that was well hidden below the plenthora of preset paper sizes!

Comment: Found this hidden feature of margins, set it as desired — and it's ignored. Firefox just keeps printing its own margins, ignoring mine.

Comment: The way this person set the margins on the `about:config` page worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/q/487531/1157519 :|